# JQuery submit() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I have this script:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="regform">
    <paper-material id="general">
            <gold-email-input pw="mail" name="mail" label="Mail" auto-validate></gold-email-input>
            <paper-input id="pw" name="pw" type="password" label="Password"></paper-input>
            <paper-input id="pwrepeat" type="password" label="Repeat password"></paper-input>

            <paper-button onClick="subform();" id="submitbutton" elevation="2" raised>Submit</paper-button>
    </paper-material>
</form>
```

```
function subform(){
        console.log("call");
        $('#regform').submit(function(e){
            console.log( "Data: " + $(this).serialize() );
            e.preventDefault(); //no difference with or without this function               
        });
    }
```

The method `submit(function(e))` is not called by the script. Why? I want to prevent the submit and use the data. Is this the right way to seralize the data from the form?

Comment: Have you tried taking out `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: You're preventing the submit function, and not the default form action

Comment: Why are you setting an event handler onclick of a button? That does not make sense

Comment: Are you *sure* the function isn't being called?  Is `"call"` not being written to the console?  What is that function even supposed to be *doing*?  Why are you duplicating the submit handler every time you click the button?  When do you actually *submit* anything?

Comment: The function is called, `call`is displayed in the console

Comment: @epascarello because i dont use the `type="submit`

Comment: Removing `preventDefault` does work, but the `submit` is still not fired

Comment: @SeseSchneider The code is setting an event...Not calling submit. That is NOT how you call the submit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code stands, the function *might* be called, depending on where your javascript code is located.

In general, using `onClick` is discouraged as it might cause nasty scoping issues. At the point, the html parser reaches your input with `onclick="subform();"`, this function has to be registered to the global scope. This is *not* the case, if you use `$(document).ready` or have the javascript at the bottom of your page.

So please check your console for errors, because either you should see the `console.log("call");` or an error message instead, which prevents the execution of your function in the first place.

Also, in the onClick handler, you are simply registering a handler for the submit event, so you could as well skip this entirely and simply register the submit handler directly.

Your code should simply look like this:

```
// this waits until your form is submitted
$('#regform').submit(function(e){
    console.log("submit button was pressed");
    console.log( "Data: " + $(this).serialize() );
    // this prevents the the actual form submit, so you have to do
    // some kind of ajax call, to get the data to the server
    e.preventDefault();             
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but i have to register the submit button to submit the form via `$("#regform").submit()`

Comment: @SeseSchneider I am not familiar with polymer - in plain html, the default action of a button is the submit action, but this may not be true for polymer.

Answer (score -2):

Try assigning your submit button an input type.

```
<input type="submit" class="paper-button" onClick="subform();" id="submitbutton" elevation="2" raised>Submit</paper-button>
```

Also, the preventdefault is going to prevent the submission. Try removing it.

**EDIT:**

As Christopher pointed out, a library is being used, so option one is not going to work. Remove the preventdefault instead.

Comment: The polymer library is being used, instead of the HTML language. If you aren't familiar with it, check it out at: https://www.polymer-project.org/

Comment: I want to prevent the form submission to use ajax but i have to use `form`

Comment: Gotcha. If you are not using a standard form submit button type, you dont need to preventDefault. You are defining in your script a function for submit, so the preventdefault is most likely preventing the button click from registering rather than your intended prevention of the default form submission.